# failed to cross compile QT using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

Tags: linux, qt, arm, mingw, cross-compiling

My platform is windows, using mingw. When cross-compiling the arm version of qt, if configure does not add -sysroot, it will report "ERROR: Cannot compile a minimal program. The toolchain or QMakeSpec is broken". But after adding -sysroot, the result of Checking for host architecture is arm. The host architecture should be x86.

## not add -sysroot

```bash
configure ^
-release ^
-opensource ^
-confirm-license ^
-prefix E:/arm32-gcc6.2.1-qt5.13.0 ^
-nomake tests ^
-nomake examples ^
-no-opengl ^
-skip qtvirtualkeyboard  ^
-xplatform linux-arm32-gnu-g++ ^
-prefix E:/arm32-gcc6.2.1-qt5.13.0 ^
-recheck-all
```

An error is reported: Checking for valid makespec... ERROR: Cannot compile a minimal program. The toolchain or QMakeSpec is broken.

## add -sysroot

```bash
configure ^
-release ^
-opensource ^
-confirm-license ^
-prefix E:/arm32-gcc6.2.1-qt5.13.0 ^
-nomake tests ^
-nomake examples ^
-no-opengl ^
-skip qtvirtualkeyboard  ^
-xplatform linux-arm32-gnu-g++ ^
-sysroot E:/lccu3/sysroot ^
-prefix E:/arm32-gcc6.2.1-qt5.13.0 ^
-recheck-all
```

After adding -sysroot , Running configuration will appear:
"Running configuration tests...
Checking for machine tuple... yes
Checking for valid makespec... yes
Checking for target architecture... arm
Checking for host architecture... arm"
I think that host architecture should be x86

Hope someone can explain why